# Proving the inequality $(1+x)^n \geq 1 + nx$ with induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I have to prove this equation with induction. $$\text{if } x > -1 \text{ then } (1+x)^n \geq 1 + nx\;\; \forall\; n \in \mathbb{N}$$

I've solved a base case (when $n = 0$), but I don't know how to prove the induction step.

Comment: The base case is $n=0$, not $x=0$

Comment: but, isn't $x$ the principal variable?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @HagenvonEitzen has mentioned, the base case $n = 0$ is true because $(1+x)^{0} = 1 \geq 1 + 0\times x$.

Now, assume $(1+x)^{n} \geq 1 + nx$. Then we have that
\begin{align*}
(1+x)^{n+1} = (1+x)^{n}(1+x) \geq (1+nx)(1+x) = 1 + (n+1)x + nx^{2} \geq 1 + (n+1)x
\end{align*}

and we are done.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thank you APCorreia. I understood better now.

Comment: You are welcome @MatheusSousa ! I am glad to help.